# Swift cast fails

Tags: swift

So I'm writing this segue method in Swift, but when I unwrap controller, it is always none. Without the `as?` it just downright fails at runtime. Whats going on?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue : UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showCoursesSegue") {
        var controller = segue.destinationViewController as? EditViewController
        controller!.test = true 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me in prepare for segue. Tried actually setting the type of controller to EditViewController and removing that `?`.

```
var dst: NoteViewController = segue.destinationViewController as NoteViewController
```

Comment: yeah it still fails doing var controller: EditViewController = segue.destinationViewController as EditViewController. the controller its going to doesnt need anything special does it? Atm EditViewController hasn't even been loaded or anything when this segue is happening

Comment: your destinationViewController will be instantiated during the segue, so it should exist at that point, since these are the last preparations before moving to the next view.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the Swift way!

```
func prepareForSegue(segue : UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    switch segue.identifier! {
    case "showCoursesSegue":
        switch segue.destinationViewController {
        case let controller as EditViewController:
            controller.test = true
        default:
            println("segue.destinationViewController is \(segue.destinationViewController)")
        }
    default:
        println("segue.identifier is \(segue.identifier)")
    }   
}
```

Comment: That results in this Swift compiler error: Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %104 = bitcast i32 %103 to i8*, !dbg !419
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1

probably a compiler bug

Comment: when I run my original code it prints segue.destinationViewController is a (Metatype) before it fails

Comment: oops sorry. It seems you're getting a `destinationViewController` that is not an `EditViewController`. I updated the `println` message for the inner `default` case.

Comment: hmm it says its a UIViewController. I have zero idea anymore.

Comment: Have you checked if the destination view controller in your storyboard  actually has its `Custom Class` set?

Comment: that was the issue here - just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that in IB, the ViewController hadn't been set up as a custom class. I'd post a picture but haven't got enough rep.